# Killing Android app 2 from app 1

Tags: android, system.exit

I have 3 android apps. If a user has app1 open, is should check to see if app2, and/or app3 are running, and if so, kill them.

Here is what I have tried.

Implemented a BroadcastReceiver() in each app.

```
mFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("intent", "Got Kill Intent, I am " + pn);
        if (killAction.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            killmePlease(pn, killAction);
        }
    }
};
registerReceiver(mFinishReceiver, intentFilter);
```

and then, using this I try to kill the app..

```
private void killmePlease(String pn) {
    Intent _killme = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(_killme);
    try {
        Log.v("intent", "Finishing " + pn);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        System.exit(0);
        Log.v("intent", "Finished");
        return;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("intent", "Error Killing " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, the apps are still running with no errors thrown. Can anyone kindly tell me what I am missing?

Comment: This is generally not something you should try to do, as it goes against the entire design philosophy of Android and so in addition to being unwise has numerous "gotchas" where you and the platform code end up working at cross-purposes.  Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @chris, there are several reasons I need to do this. The 3 apps are games. They each share a library that provides a 'portal' to the other games. This library includes a WebView, and via javascript, the app sends out an intent to start the game of choice (via a competition list). I know it sounds funky, and it is kinda hard to explain.

Game 1 -> Webview with link buttons to Game 1, Game 2, Game 3)

Player starts Game 1, webview opens. They then decide to view competitions for Game 2. Game 1 should close until the player is interested in actually viewing the competitions for Game 1 (etc)

Comment: Android is designed to take care of that for you.  First decide if you have a problem, then see what possibilities may already be provided by the webviews.  The intent is that killing a process should never be the right answer, so for you to think it is you are either doing something extremely *obscure*, trying to work around a platform *bug* or shortsightedness - or mostly likely of all, not yet thinking in accordance with the design intent of Android.

Comment: @chris, thank you for your input. I often see replies in forums questioning the questioner as to why they want or need to do a particular thing. I guess that is the direction things are tending now-a-days, or I am possibly just too old school :)

Comment: I personally wish that Android were much more of a conventional Linux platform; but at the same time, for code that will be distributed to other people, one really needs to make a solid effort to try to solve the problem (if there even is one) in a way compatible with the platform as a whole, before striking out in a contrary direction.  Right now, you seem to have a very odd mix of "Activity is orthagonal to process" Android Intent usage, with a more unix-y "just kill it already" attempt, and the two are not going to mesh well.